# What type of index is most suitable for a low-selective column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-10

I have table with around 60M of records and potentially it will grow up to ~500M soon (then will be growing slowly). In the table there is a column, say category. Total number of categories is around 20K and grows very slow and occasionally. Records are not distributed evenly among categories, there are categories that cover 5% of all records while other categories are represented by only very small proportion of records.

I have number of queries that work only with one or several categories (use `=` or `IN`/`ANY` conditions) and I want to optimize performance of these queries.

1. Taking into account low-selective nature of data in the column, which type of Postgres index will be more beneficial: HASH or B-TREE?
2. Are there any other ways to optimize performance of these queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only give a generalized answer to this broad question.

Use B-tree indexes, not hash indexes.

If you have several conditions that are not very selective, create an index on each of the columns, then they can be combined with a bitmap index scan.

Comment: Could you comment why? They write hash indices are bit faster than btree: https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/hash-indexes-are-faster-btree-indexes Is it due to low selectivity?

Comment: B-tree indexes are just more tested, while hash indexes have only become useful recently. But you are right - maybe you should benchmark them for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a column that is not very selective is not a good candidate for an index.  Indexes are not free.  They need to be maintained, and at query-time, in most cases, Postgres will still have to go out to the table for each row the index search matches (exception is covering indexes).

With that said, I'm not sure of your selectivity analysis. If the highest percent you'll filter down to worst-case is 5%, and most are far lower than that, that I'd say you have a very selective column.

As for which index type to use, b-tree versus hash, I generally go with a b-tree index as my standard unless there is a specific need to deviate.

Hash indexes are faster to query than b-tree indexes, but, they cannot be used for range lookups, only equality.  Hash indexes are not supported on all RDBMS's, and as a result, are less well understood in the community, which can hinder support.

Comment: I know this information about hash indices, but as I said this column will only be used with `=` and `IN`. It is absolutely unlikely that range conditions will be applied. Why do you still think hash is not a good choice here?

Comment: As mentioned, they are not well understood in the community.  If a problem occurs, it will be harder to get help.  When people think about indexes, they think of b-trees.

Comment: Here is a hash index problem I just discovered.  My lack of expertise with them would have bitten me if I didn't carefully read the documentation to notice they are not WAL-logged, which goes to crash-safety: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-types.html

Comment: There is a reason why b-tree is the Postgres default.

Comment: There is no such notice in the current version: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-types.html